# How do I receive a POST in an asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, html, http, post

This may seem like a silly question. We have a streaming server and the manual says that it can authenticate by performing a post to a http server and the http server responds with e couple if lines of text.

How does this work in practice in asp.net? Do i need to create the physcial .aspx file and then set a breakpoint on that file and wait for the request to that page?

I have to read values from the header of the post does this mean I basically just read the page variables like the Request[] etc?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you will have to look at the Request.Headers["Username"] in your on_load event. If you don't know which vars to look for you can use a http sniffer like fiddler to inspect the header to see which variables you need to look at but this should be in the manual.

Comment: thats cool but how do I get fiddler to see incoming traffic? when i browse to my local machine from aa dev machine nothing comes up....

Comment: Localhost. (the dot) instead of Localhost in the url will show traffic

Comment: Sorry im confused. I dont actually use locahost Ive got my local machine set up on DNS. So when I broswe my machine (from another machine) NOT localhost how do i see incoming traffic?

Comment: ok,sorry about that, fiddler needs to run on the machine you are sending the httpRequest from and not on the server hosting the aspx page.